# How can I build my own custom android ROM?

Tags: android, rom

Nice to meet everybody.

I have a ***Samsung J5 Pro*** and would like to build my own **custom android ROM** from **Google Source**. I am programmer and I use **Linux Ubuntu** and would like to create from **stage zero**, is there any step by step tutorial for me to follow? If you have to Samsung smartphone will be cool, but any text already helps.

***Thanks and it's good to be back in the forum stackoverflow. I love this place.***

Comment: Probably xdadevelopers is good place to start.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the mehodology to "cook" a ROM. Like NiVeR said, move over to xda-developers.com and look for ROM cooking tutorials. You are stepping into the realm where nobody likes to help a newbie who hasn't got his hands dirty. Most developers wouldn't even comment on things if you havent tried out the basics. So Good luck and happy hacking.

Comment: ok, I will try. Thank you so much.